# C++ Version For Java String.replaceAll

Tags: c++

[Java String.replaceAll](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) comes very handy.

Has anyone encounter similar library in C++ (Even without regular expression match, but with exact match is OK)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494399/how-do-i-search-find-and-replace-in-an-stl-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has no built in lib to do that, but Boost has string replace functions:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1701549

Also without STL here is an example:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/replace-a-substring-with-another-string-in-c-170076/