# How to find and replace string?

Tags: c++, string

If `s` is a `std::string`, then is there a function like the following?

```
s.replace("text to replace", "new text");
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

Comment: There is no such direct replace, but it should have been there. I was also searching for the same for a long time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Search/Find and Replace in a standard string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494399/how-do-i-search-find-and-replace-in-a-standard-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace part of a string with another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Replace first match

Use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find the first occurrence of the string `toReplace`.
Use [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) to replace that occurrence with the string `replaceWith`.

This function does that:

```
void replace_first(
    std::string& s,
    std::string const& toReplace,
    std::string const& replaceWith
) {
    std::size_t pos = s.find(toReplace);
    if (pos == std::string::npos) return;
    s.replace(pos, toReplace.length(), replaceWith);
}
```

Usage:

```
replace_first(s, "text to replace", "new text");
```

[Demo.](https://replit.com/@SicariusNoctis/how-to-find-and-replace-string-replacefirst)

---

### Replace all matches

Define this O(n) method using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_string) as a buffer:

```
void replace_all(
    std::string& s,
    std::string const& toReplace,
    std::string const& replaceWith
) {
    std::string buf;
    std::size_t pos = 0;
    std::size_t prevPos;

    // Reserves rough estimate of final size of string.
    buf.reserve(s.size());

    while (true) {
        prevPos = pos;
        pos = s.find(toReplace, pos);
        if (pos == std::string::npos)
            break;
        buf.append(s, prevPos, pos - prevPos);
        buf += replaceWith;
        pos += toReplace.size();
    }

    buf.append(s, prevPos, s.size() - prevPos);
    s.swap(buf);
}
```

Usage:

```
replace_all(s, "text to replace", "new text");
```

[Demo.](https://replit.com/@SicariusNoctis/how-to-find-and-replace-string-replaceall)

---

#### Boost

Alternatively, use [`boost::algorithm::replace_all`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using boost::replace_all;
```

Usage:

```
replace_all(s, "text to replace", "new text");
```

Comment: if "text to replace" is longer or shorter than the length of the "new text", what will the string::replace do? memmove the string to fill the gap?

Comment: @Alcott It'll allocate memory for a "new" `string` of the correct size, fill in the data, and delete the "old" `string`.

Comment: I think it is a bit confusing to accept a string as reference and return it: It is not clear without reading the code what is the returned string or if I need to save it. I would just return `void` or accept const std::string& s, but not both.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I was trying to match the signature of `std::string::replace`, but I agree that it's a bit confusing, so I've changed it for now.

Answer (score 35):

Do we really need a Boost library for seemingly such a simple task?

To replace all occurences of a substring use this function:

```
std::string ReplaceString(std::string subject, const std::string& search,
                          const std::string& replace) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
         subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
         pos += replace.length();
    }
    return subject;
}
```

If you need performance, here is an optimized function that modifies the input string, it does not create a copy of the string:

```
void ReplaceStringInPlace(std::string& subject, const std::string& search,
                          const std::string& replace) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
         subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
         pos += replace.length();
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
std::string input = "abc abc def";
std::cout << "Input string: " << input << std::endl;

std::cout << "ReplaceString() return value: " 
          << ReplaceString(input, "bc", "!!") << std::endl;
std::cout << "ReplaceString() input string not modified: " 
          << input << std::endl;

ReplaceStringInPlace(input, "bc", "??");
std::cout << "ReplaceStringInPlace() input string modified: " 
          << input << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Input string: abc abc def
ReplaceString() return value: a!! a!! def
ReplaceString() input string not modified: abc abc def
ReplaceStringInPlace() input string modified: a?? a?? def
```

Comment: I say: yes, because it replaces your own code with peer-reviewed code. The same reason you're using std::string and std::cout.  
  
Now, if you're trying to reduce dependencies, that's another question.

Comment: The issue with replace() being called many times is that each time it might be moving the right hand part of the string (assuming the "replace" is not the same length as the "find".

Therefore if memory is not an issue I'd prefer to write everything to a new string.

Comment: calling this with an empty search string results in an infinite loop. perhaps return subject if search.empty() is true. (drawback: this makes it so you can't search for an empty string and replace it with a non-empty string).

Answer (score 25):

Yes: [`replace_all`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html) is one of the boost string algorithms:

Although it's not a standard library, it has a few things on the standard library:

1. *More natural notation* based on ranges rather than iterator pairs. This is nice because you can nest string manipulations (e.g., `replace_all` nested inside a `trim`). That's a bit more involved for the standard library functions.
2. *Completeness.* This isn't hard to be 'better' at; the standard library is fairly spartan. For example, the boost string algorithms give you explicit control over how string manipulations are performed (i.e., in place or through a copy).

Comment: +1: this boost library seems little known, yet it's perhaps the one I use the most.

Answer (score 19):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string str("one three two four");
    string str2("three");
    str.replace(str.find(str2),str2.length(),"five");
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
one five two four
```

Comment: This might crash if the string is not found

Comment: @yoelhalb With fixed data, it's never going to crash.  This is just an example with no error checking.

Answer (score 7):

like some say boost::replace_all

here a dummy example:

```
    #include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

    std::string path("file.gz");
    boost::replace_all(path, ".gz", ".zip");
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly that, but `std::string` has many [`replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)  overloaded functions.

Go through [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) to see explanation of each, with examples as to how they're used.

Also, there are several versions of [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) functions (listed below) which you can use in conjunction with `string::replace`.

- find
- rfind
- find_first_of
- find_last_of
- find_first_not_of
- find_last_not_of

---

Also, note that there are several versions of `replace` functions available from `<algorithm>` which you can also use (instead of `string::replace`):

- replace
- replace_if
- replace_copy
- replace_copy_if

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: find or rfind are the only appropriate ones.

std::replace works for string only if it is char-to-char replace i.e. replacing all the spaces with underscores or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

```
// replaced text will be in buffer.
void Replace(char* buffer, const char* source, const char* oldStr,  const char* newStr)
{
    if(buffer==NULL || source == NULL || oldStr == NULL || newStr == NULL) return; 

    int slen = strlen(source);
    int olen = strlen(oldStr);
    int nlen = strlen(newStr);

    if(olen>slen) return;
    int ix=0;

    for(int i=0;i<slen;i++)
    {
        if(oldStr[0] == source[i])
        {
            bool found = true;
            for(int j=1;j<olen;j++)
            {
                if(source[i+j]!=oldStr[j])
                {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(found)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<nlen;j++)
                    buffer[ix++] = newStr[j];

                i+=(olen-1);
            }
            else
            {
                buffer[ix++] = source[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[ix++] = source[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice function, but doesn't handle squeezing space characters very well. For example, replace two spaces with one space would have to be run multiple times to get just one space between characters in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a function like the following?

One other(*in addition to using `boost` and other methods given in different answers*) possible way of doing this is using [`std::regex_replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) as shown below:

```
    std::string s{"my name is my name and not my name mysometext myto"}; //this is the original line
    
    std::string replaceThis = "my";
    std::string replaceWith = "your";
    
    std::regex pattern("\\b" + replaceThis + "\\b");
    
    std::string replacedLine = std::regex_replace(s, pattern, replaceWith);

    std::cout<<replacedLine<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the version I ended up writing that replaces all instances of the target string in a given string. Works on any string type.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
T &replace (
          T &str, 
    const U &from, 
    const U &to)
{
    size_t pos;
    size_t offset = 0;
    const size_t increment = to.size();

    while ((pos = str.find(from, offset)) != T::npos)
    {
        str.replace(pos, from.size(), to);
        offset = pos + increment;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Example:

```cpp
auto foo = "this is a test"s;
replace(foo, "is"s, "wis"s);
cout << foo;
```

Output:

```cpp
thwis wis a test
```

Note that even if the search string appears in the replacement string, this works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
void replace(char *str, char *strFnd, char *strRep)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        int npos = -1, j, k;
        if (str[i] == strFnd[0])
        {
            for (j = 1, k = i+1; j < strlen(strFnd); j++)
                if (str[k++] != strFnd[j])
                    break;
            npos = i;
        }
        if (npos != -1)
            for (j = 0, k = npos; j < strlen(strRep); j++)
                str[k++] = strRep[j];
    }

}

int main()
{
    char pst1[] = "There is a wrong message";
    char pfnd[] = "wrong";
    char prep[] = "right";

    cout << "\nintial:" << pst1;

    replace(pst1, pfnd, prep);

    cout << "\nfinal : " << pst1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void replaceAll(std::string & data, const std::string &toSearch, const std::string &replaceStr)
{
    // Get the first occurrence
    size_t pos = data.find(toSearch);
    // Repeat till end is reached
    while( pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        // Replace this occurrence of Sub String
        data.replace(pos, toSearch.size(), replaceStr);
        // Get the next occurrence from the current position
        pos =data.find(toSearch, pos + replaceStr.size());
    }
}
```

More CPP utilities: https://github.com/Heyshubham/CPP-Utitlities/blob/master/src/MEString.cpp#L60