# Replace function in C++

Tags: c++, replace

I have one string A B C. I need to replace space with underscore(_) in C++. Is there any function like we have in perl or java?

Input:

```
   char* string =  "A B C"
```

Output

```
    A_B_C
```

Comment: Consider `std::string` for your purposes...

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5878775/1084416)

Comment: I have chararacter string (char*), so don't want to use std::string functions.

Comment: @user15662 Why didn't you say so immediately?

Comment: you can always use std::string(char *) constructor and output string.c_str() output. Depends what kind of operations do you need. If size of string cannot change as in this case, just loop with strpos and replace.

Comment: NOTE: There is something inherently wrong with the question that is not addressed in the *duplicate* answers. The code in the question is obtaining a non-const pointer to a literal, which is a deprecated feature of the language. While the pointer is non-const, the literal is const, and trying to change it's contents (for the substitution) is undefined behavior. As others have mentioned, you need to start by creating a copy (`std::string` would be the natural choice, operate on that and then get a `char*` back if you need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent `replace` member function.

You must first [`search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) for the space and then use [`std::string::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

```
char *string = "A B C";
std::string s(string);
size_t pos = s.find(' ');
if (pos != std::string::npos)
    s.replace(pos, 1, "_");
```

With just a `char*`, put it first in a `std::string` and then apply one of the answers here.

If you want to avoid `std::string` and `std::string` methods altogether, use [`std::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/) as the other answers already suggested

```
std::replace(string, string + strlen(string), ' ', '_');
```

or if you already know the string length

```
std::replace(string, string + len, ' ', '_');
```

But keep in mind, that you cannot modify a constant string literal.

If you want to do it manually, [c](/questions/tagged/c) style

```
static inline void manual_c_string_replace(char *s, char from, char to)
{
    for (; *s != 0; ++s)
        if (*s == from)
            *s = to;
}
```

Comment: std::string function are very expensive. I need to do this 1 million times. It will slow down the speed.

Comment: @user15662 Then use `std::replace`, as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 7):

There is `std::replace`

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::replace (s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', '_');
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's `std::replace()` defined in `<algorithm>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string input("A B C");
  std::replace(input.begin(), input.end(), ' ', '_');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is `std::replace` function

```
std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), 'x', 'y'); // replace all 'x' to 'y'
```

Comment: Amazingly similar to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2896627/597607