# I want to save the processed image from OpenCV as the `input_name+enhanced.input_image_format`

Tags: c++

Let assume my input image name is `cat.jpg` after I processed the image I want to save the output image as `cat_enhanced.jpg`. How do I can do like that?

I don't know how to access the image name and format separately.

```
char* inputImgName = argv[1];
```

This code store both image name and format in the `inputImgName` pointer.

[Edited]

```
std::string imgNameString = argv[1];
```

Using this I can get the `cat.jpg`, but don't know how to save the image as described above.

Expected output: 
input image name: `cat.jpg` 
output image name: `cat_enhanced.jpg`

Comment: You'd be better off with a std::string to handle the memory allocation and reallocation for you. But if you want to use a char pointer, you'll have to allocate the memory yourself; you shouldn't point it to argv[1] and munge that memory.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I edited my question. Do you know how to save the image as I asked above.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878775/how-to-find-and-replace-string

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and report to you.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Thank you, that solved my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer to my question. Thanks @ L. Scott Johnson for pointing me out.

```
std::string inputImgName = argv[1];
std::string findFormat(".");
size_t pos = inputImgName.find(findFormat);
inputImgName.replace(pos, findFormat.length(), "_enhanced.");
cout << "The enhanced image name is: " << inputImgName << endl;
```