# How to replace a value in a string with another in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, data-manipulation, stdstring

if I have a string eg

```
2,4,-1,3,-1,
```

how do I replace all the -1's with the word "wrong"? and how do I remove the comma at the very end?
the output has come from an array

```
cout<<array[c]<<",";
```

I need a basic solution please
thank you

Comment: `cout<<array[c]<<","` *does not produce* a string; it writes to the standard output.

Comment: You need to show more context. You don't really have a string at all in the example. Or at least its not clear. I am not sure that array is a `std::string`

Comment: Here is how you replace part of a `std::string` [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Comment: Why not do the `cout` differently in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand what you are trying to say, better if you edit your question. You could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878775/how-to-find-and-replace-string/14678964#14678964) (stackoverflow answer),

```
  std::string subject("2,4,-1,3,-1,");
  std::string search("-1");
  std::string replace("wrong");
  size_t pos = 0;

  while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos) 
  {
    subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
    pos += replace.length();
  }

  // Delete last ,
  subject.pop_back();

  std::cout << subject;
```