# Replacing std::strings

Tags: c++, string

My string is `std::string str ("DDWD");`

I want to change the corresponding to the following

```
D = [0-9] W = [a-z]
```

soo...`("[0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9]")`

The replace method does not seem to accomade this, so i tried something like

```
string tmp = "DDDWD";   
int len = 0;   
len = tmp.length();   
for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
{
    if ( tmp[i] == 'D')
    {  
        tmp.replace(i,1,"[0-9]");  
        i+=2;  
    }
}
```

However trying to change both letters D and W there was a problem and it wasent changing them all correctly?

Does anyone know a way how to change each letter at the same time to the corresponding string above?

Thankful for any help

Comment: What is the "problem"?  What is the output you actually got?  What did you observe when you stepped through this in the debugger?

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494399/how-do-i-search-find-and-replace-in-a-standard-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be cleaner if you used a separate string:

```
string tmp = "DDDWD";
string tmp2;

for (int i=0; i<tmp.size(); ++i)
{
    if (tmp[i] == 'D')
        tmp2 += "[0-9]";
    else if (tmp[i] == 'W')
        tmp2 += "[a-z]";
    else
        tmp2 += tmp[i];
}

tmp.swap(tmp2);

// or in C++11
// tmp = std::move(tmp2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like you're just ending your loop early.

```
len = tmp.length();

for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )

{
```

...so you save the length to iterate, and even if the string gets longer, you'll stop at the old length.

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` method works with positions, not substrings. So replacing would be a two-step process: `find` first, then `replace` with the results of the `find`, until `find` no longer finds anything.

But the way you do it also works, if you run the loop backwards (start at the end and work your way down).

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, use Boost's [String Algo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3115542) library. It has lots of useful algorithms on strings. Your problem would then read:

```
  // #include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>
  std::string tmp = "DDDWD"; 
  boost::replace_all( tmp, "D", "[0-9]" );
  boost::replace_all( tmp, "W", "[a-z]" );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
  std::string tmp = "DDDWD";
  char *tmp2=new char(5*(strlen(tmp.c_str()) +1)); 
  cout << "tmp is " << tmp;


  for (int i=0; i<tmp.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (tmp[i] == 'D' && i==0)
    tmp2 = strcpy(tmp2,"[0-9]");
    else if(tmp[i] == 'D' && i!=0) 
    tmp2 = strcat(tmp2,"[0-9]");   
    else if (tmp[i] == 'W' && i==0)
    tmp2 = strcpy(tmp2,"[a-z]");
    else if (tmp[i] == 'W' && i!=0)
    tmp2 = strcat(tmp2,"[a-z]");
  }

  cout << "tmp2 is :" << tmp2;

  getchar();   
}
```

Comment: If you null-terminate tmp2 from the start, you can just use strcat everytime.  Then you don't need the extra logic of checking if `i==0` or `i!=0`

Comment: @Andrzej I tried implementing the boost thing you mentioned , but i get an error saying it is not able to include replace.hpp file as you mentioned . Is it not available in standard C++