# Parse string and swap substrings

Tags: c++, c, string

How can I parse a string given by a user and swap all occurrences of the old substring with the new string.  I have a function to work with but I am really uncertain when it comes to strings.

```
void spliceSwap( char* inputStr, const char* oldStr, const char* newStr  )
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Can we see the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Is this in C or C++? If it's C++, use `std::string`. If it's C, tag it appropriately.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use google ([First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494399/how-do-i-search-find-and-replace-in-a-standard-string)) here. Also be aware that in C++ we prefer `std::string` over `const char *`. Do not write your own `std::string`, use the built-in one. Your code seems to be more **C** than C++!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Zammbi's variable names will help answer your  question   
// params find and replace cannot be NULL
void FindAndReplace( std::string& source, const char* find, const char* replace )
{
   // ASSERT(find != NULL);
   // ASSERT(replace != NULL);
   size_t findLen = strlen(find);
   size_t replaceLen = strlen(replace);
   size_t pos = 0;

   // search for the next occurrence of find within source
   while ((pos = source.find(find, pos)) != std::string::npos)
   {
      // replace the found string with the replacement
      source.replace( pos, findLen, replace );

      // the next line keeps you from searching your replace string, 
      // so your could replace "hello" with "hello world" 
      // and not have it blow chunks.
      pos += replaceLen; 
   }
}
```