# Char* replace with char*

Tags: c++, string, boost, replace, char

I want to replace my text with boost like php.

```
char* find = "a abc text";
char* search[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
char* replace[] = { "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
boost::replace_all(find, search, replace);
```

But he can't convert "char* const" to "int".

Comment: It appears you are trying to do something similar to: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4289916/2690204)  You may want to look at how replace_all works, you are not passing a string along for search and replace.

Comment: "he can't convert" is not a good, scientific problem description. To make this a good question for SO, describe in detail the problem you face, including error messages and what you did to solve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ string literals (like `"a abc text"`) are *read only*, attempting to modify a string literal will lead to *undefined behavior*. That's why the code you show should cause the compiler to give you a warning (that you have a non-const pointer to const data), and if the compiler doesn't warn you then you need to enable more warnings. A pointer to a string literal should always by `char const*` or the more common `const char *`.

If you want a modifiable string, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (or if you want C-style string use arrays of `char`, like `char find[] = "a abc text"`).

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to use boost for something as trivial as this.

```
char value[]        = "foobar";
const char *search  = "abcde";
const char *replace = "fghij";

size_t i, j, k = strlen(value);

for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    for (j = 0; j < k; j ++) {
        if (value[j] == search[i])
            value[j] = replace[i];
    }
}
```

Note that this code assumes that there are 5 characters in `search` and `replace`. Also note that if `search` and `replace` overlap, there will be unexpected behaviour. If that is important to you, you should switch the order of for-loops (i.e. first `j < k`, then `i < 5`).

Comment: But it's more expressive to encapsulate that logic in a function, and more convenient to use a function already made for you and well-tested.