# How can I make the loop account for multiple occurrences?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a code that backspaces for every time the character `<` is found in the string.

The code I have only seems to do it the first time it appears and nothing happens in the succeeding times it appears.

Any tips on how to fix please? Is there a more efficient loop I can use?

```
void decodeback(string orig, string search, string replace) {
  size_t pos = 0;
  do {
    pos = orig.find(search, pos);
    if (pos == string::npos)
      break;
    orig.erase(pos, search.length());
    orig.erase(pos - 1, search.length());

    cout << orig << endl;
  } while (pos += replace.length());
}

int main() {
  // input the question
  string question = "What is the message? ";
  // output the answer
  string answer = "The real message is ";

  // special characters
  string shift = "^";
  string back = "<";
  string test = "a";

  // input the coded message
  string answer1;

  // output decoded message
  string answer2;

  cout << question;
  cin >> answer1;
  cout << "decoding ";

  decodeback(answer1, back, test);

  return 0;
}
```

Example input:

```
hello<<
```

Desired output:

```
hel
```

Actual output:

```
hell<
```

Comment: It is not really clear what your `decodeback` is supposed to do. For example the method does not use the `replace` parameter, other than adding its length to the `pos`, which might be the reason for finding only the first occurence

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use your debugger. You should be abkle to find this kind of simple problems yourself. I also suggest you read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part does not do what you want :

```
while(pos += replace.length());
```

Furthermore, `pos` is not adjusted after erasing two characters.

These two mean that you can skip over `'<'` characters.

Instead, try :

```
while (true) {
    pos = orig.find(search, pos);
    if(pos == string::npos)
        break;
    orig.erase(pos--, search.length());
    orig.erase(pos, search.length());

    cout<<orig<<endl;
}
```

Note that this code assumes there will never be a `'<'` character as the first character of the string, or bad things will happen.

It also assumes that `search.length()` will always be `1`, or the second `erase` call will not do what's expected. That second `erase` call should probably just be :

```
orig.erase(pos, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is that your loop condition is broken

```
while(pos += replace.length())
```

On a higher level, i would suggest using boost for example, they have some neat string algorithms.

See for example, this answer:
[How do I Search/Find and Replace in a standard string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494399/how-do-i-search-find-and-replace-in-a-standard-string)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention right, the first thing to do is to move the following line out of the `do-while` loop in `decodeback` function.

```
cout << orig << endl;
```

This is because you want to print the string after removing all the `<` s that have been found.
If you do not want the `<` to be replaced by anything else, you can also remove the second erase, i.e. the following line from the do-while loop.

```
orig.erase(pos - 1, search.length());
```